# How to retrieve formated date field in sqlite in my android code?

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have following code in my android program:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ID,firstname,date(birthday) from user", null);  
String birthdaystr=cursor.getString(2);
```

But the value of birthdaystr is null.

I changed my code to:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ID,firstname,birthday from user", null);  
String birthdaystr=cursor.getString(2);
```

The value of birthdaystr looks like "Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 +0000 1973".

Anybody know this issue? (It seems I need to get the value by another way if I use date() function)

Answer (score 1):

Use `strftime` function to retrieve formated date.

```
strftime(" + "\"%Y" + "-" + "%m" + "-" + "%d\"" + ",birthday)
```

or Use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formatted = sdf.format(new Date(birthdaystr));
```

You can apply any date format what you want.

Comment: Thanks Chirag. strftime() has the same issue as date() function. And I also try your 2nd solution. But "new Date(birthdaystr)" will lead to an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
....
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ID,firstname,birthday from user", null);  
String birthdaystr=cursor.getString(2);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formatted = sdf.format(new Date(birthdaystr));
.....
```

Comment: Thanks appserv. "new Date(birthdaystr)" will lead to an exception. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ID,firstname,birthday from user", null);  
String birthdaystr=cursor.getString(2);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:m:ss dd-MM-yyyy");
String TimeStampDB = sdf.format(new Date(birthdaystr));
```